# return a series of keys based on value python randomly generated in separate line

Tags: python, dictionary, random, key, key-value

I'm trying to return a series of values when randomly generating a number which then corresponds to a certain key.

This is a miniature version of my dictionary (key = word, value = character count) :

---

```
import random

myDict = {
"lire": "4",
"l'art": "5",
"écrire": "6",
"écouter": "7",
"compter": "7",
"répéter": "7",
"étudier": "7",
"aller à": "7",
"calculer": "8",
"regarder": "8"}
```

---

I tried two options.

1)

```
def search(myDict, lookup):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        for v in value:
            if lookup in v:
                return key

print(search(myDict, str(random.randint(4,10)))
```

2. 

```
print([k for k, v in myDict.items() if v == 'random.randint(4,10)'])
```

Both options work when the value is "4" and print lire or ['lire'] respectively.
However, when the value is 4 (without quotation marks) or random.randint(4,10) or 'random.randint(4,10)', it returns [].

The value seemingly has to be a string but if I search for the random function in '' then it obviously does not return a key because none of the values are called 'random.randint(4,10)'.

If someone could find a solution where I can link the two sections (randomly generated number and valid set of keys from random value), that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do you want to return a random key that has certain value?

Comment: `range(4, 5)` only contains `4`, it makes no sense to select something randomly from it.

Comment: Why did you put `'random.sample(range(4,5), 1)'` in quotes? That makes it a string literal, it doesn't execute it.

Comment: If you want a random number between `4` and `5`, use `random.randint(4, 5)`

Comment: @Barmar, that's absolutely what I should have gone for. But I still don't get a result when I put random.randint(4, 5) with/without quotation marks.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I want to return a key from a random value.

Comment: The problem is that it re-executes `random.randint()` each time through the loop. You should pick a random number first and put it in a variable, then use that in the list comprehension.

Comment: @Barmar I think I tried that by saying word = randomrandint(4,10) and then print([k for k, v in myDict.items() if v == 'word') or print([k for k, v in myDict.items() if v == word) and neither worked.

Comment: Why do you keep putting quotes around expressions? This seems like you're just trying random things without understanding what you're doing.

Comment: @Barmar I really appreciate the help. It's only my 3rd hour of doing python and I'm trying to learn by doing. I can't get your solution to work - would you mind explaining it again? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick the random value first. If you call `random.randint()` in the list comprehension, each value is compared to a potentially different random number.

```
choice = str(random.randint(4, 5))
print([k for k, v in myDict.items() if v == choice])
```

`str()` is needed above because the values in your dictionary are strings, but `random.randint()` returns an integer.

If you want any possible value, not just `4` or `5`, use:

```
choice = random.choice(list(set(myDict.values())))
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/ynB2b1)

Comment: If you can get it to work then please explain how because neither of those options work when I try to run the code.

Comment: It works for me, I've added a link to a demo.